# How to disable ContextMenu on child elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want disable ContextMenu on child controls in grid, but when the user click on grid in margine zone between elements must seem ContextMenu.

I have this code:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Item1"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Item2"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>

    <!-- Just example. In future will some collections -->
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="123" ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: By design you can't prevent it. You may assign `ContextMenu` to that control where exaclty it must appear instead of parent `Grid`. Or consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40402811/12888024)

Answer (score 0):

UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="AmazingMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Item1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Item2"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="MegaGrid" Background="Transparent" MouseRightButtonDown="Grid_MouseRightButtonDown">
    <!-- Some controls -->
</Grid>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs

```
private void Grid_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var control = e.OriginalSource as Grid;

    if (control.Name.Equals("MegaGrid"))
    {
        MegaGrid.ContextMenu = FindResource("AmazingMenu") as ContextMenu;
    }
    else
    {
        MegaGrid.ContextMenu = null;
    }
}
```